# How to find co-ordinates or Cell of picture object?

Tags: excel-2007, excel, vba

In Excel I have attached a picture to a cell using the following

```
Sub InsertPic()
    Dim mPic As Picture
    With ActiveSheet.Range("D12")
         Set mPic = .Parent.Pictures.Insert("C:\abc.png")
         mPic.Top = .Top
         mPic.Left = .Left
         mPic.Placement = xlMoveAndSize
     End With
 End Sub
```

Excel doesn't allow inserting pictures into cells but places it on it or attaches to it.

At run-time I need to find which Cell the picture is associated to, is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `.TopLeftCell` property.

Comment: Debug.Print mPic.TopLeftCell.Address worked gives address of cell